# Creating a regex for mongoose URI

Tags: regex, mongoose, uri

I'm trying to figure out how to validate mongoose URIs with regex. My current regex is this:

```
^(mongodb:\/{2})(\w*?):{0,1}(\w*?)@{0,1}(\w+?):(\d+)\/(\w+?)
```

I need to be able to detect if a username and password is entered, i.e.

```
mongodb:username:password@localhost:27107/mydatabasename
```

So I need these cases to be invalid:

```
mongodb://username:localhost:27107/adfaeadf
mongodb://username:@localhost:27107/adfaeadf
mongodb://:password@localhost:27107/adfaeadf
```

but have these cases be valid:

```
mongodb://:@localhost:27107/mydatabasename
mongodb://@localhost:27107/mydatabasename
mongodb://localhost:27107/mydatabasename
mongodb:username:password@localhost:27107/mydatabasename
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(mongodb:(?:\/{2})?)((\w+?):(\w+?)@|:?@?)(\w+?):(\d+)\/(\w+?)$
```

http://regex101.com/r/mV2cR7/2 for the explanation

For your last link, is there supposed to be "//" after "mongodb:"? The regex will match it either way however.

Comment: Perhaps `^(mongodb:(?:\/{2})?)((\w+?):(\w+?)@|:?@?)(\w+?)(:(\d+))?\/(\w+?)$` as the above doesn't match `mongodb://localhost/mydb`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support passing arguments:

```
/^mongodb:\/\/(?:(?:(\w+)?:(\w+)?@)|:?@?)((?:[\w.-])+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([\w-]+))?(?:\?([\w-]+=[\w-]+(?:&[\w-]+=[\w-]+)*)?)?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

this won't match for servers of the format `server-a1.host.com` (e.g. other than localhosts) or replica sets, try:

`^(mongodb:(?:\/{2})?)((\w+?):(\w+?)@|:?@?)(\S+?):(\d+)\/(\S+?)(\?replicaSet=(\S+?))?$`

explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/mV2cR7/47

Answer (score 1):

For mongodb+srv for mongodb atlas urls.

```
^(mongodb?(\+srv):(?:\/{2})?)((\w+?):(\w+?)@|:?@?)(\w+?):(\d+)\/(\w+?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for my case. for mongodb atlas uri

```js
mongodb?(\+srv):\/\/(?:(?<login>[^\:\/\?\#\[\]\@]+)(?::(?<password>[^\:\/\?\#\[\]\@]+))?@)?(?<host>[\w\.\-]+(?::\d+)?(?:,[\w\.\-]+(?::\d+)?)*)(?:\/(?<dbname>[\w\.\-]+))?(?:\?(?<query>[\w\.\-]+=[\w\.\-]+(?:&[\w\.\-]+=[\w.\-]+)*))?
```

Answer (score 1):

The following adjustment on the answers above accepts both mongodb+svr and legacy mongodb formats.

```
mongodb?([\+srv]*):\/\/(?:(?<login>[^\:\/\?\#\[\]\@]+)(?::(?<password>[^\:\/\?\#\[\]\@]+))?@)?(?<host>[\w\.\-]+(?::\d+)?(?:,[\w\.\-]+(?::\d+)?)*)(?:\/(?<dbname>[\w\.\-]+))?(?:\?(?<query>[\w\.\-]+=[\w\.\-]+(?:&[\w\.\-]+=[\w.\-]+)*))?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want support multiple shards on host and passing arguments:

```regex
/^mongodb:\/\/(?:(?:(\w+)?:(\w+)?@)|:?@?)(((?:[\w.-])+)(?::(\d+)),((?:[\w.-])+)(?::(\d+)),((?:[\w.-])+)(?::(\d+)))?(?:\/([\w-]+))?(?:\?([\w-]+=[\w-]+(?:&[\w-]+=[\w-]+)*)?)?$/g
```

Answer (score 0):

My version with named grouping:

```
/mongodb:\/\/(?:(?<login>[^\:\/\?\#\[\]\@]+)(?::(?<password>[^\:\/\?\#\[\]\@]+))?@)?(?<host>[\w\.\-]+(?::\d+)?(?:,[\w\.\-]+(?::\d+)?)*)(?:\/(?<dbname>[\w\.\-]+))?(?:\?(?<query>[\w\.\-]+=[\w\.\-]+(?:&[\w\.\-]+=[\w.\-]+)*))?/gm
```

Tested here: https://regex101.com/r/34kvZw/1